# What is wrong with my summon command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to summon a Skeleton wearing full Diamond Armor riding on an invisible bat, but it says:

> Cannot summon the object out of the world.

Here is the command:

```
summon Skeleton 0 ~ 0 {Equipment:[{id:minecraft:bow},{id:minecraft:diamond_boots},{id:minecraft:diamond_leggings},{id:minecraft:diamond_chestplate},{id:minecraft:diamond_helmet},AbsorptionAmount:20,Riding:{id:"Bat",ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999,Ambient:1}]}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates are pointing to unloaded chunks. You will either need to load those chunks or change the coordinates to point to loaded chunks.

If you were intending to summon the skeleton relative to the command sender's location, you will want to use `~` to indicate relative coordinates as you've done for the Y value.

```
summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{id:minecraft:bow},{id:minecraft:diamond_boots},{id:minecraft:diamond_leggings},{id:minecraft:diamond_chestplate},{id:minecraft:diamond_helmet},AbsorptionAmount:20,Riding:{id:"Bat",ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999,Ambient:1}]}}
```